# What happens when you flicker a double-faced card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-double-faced-cards

If I were to cast [Restoration Angel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Restoration%20Angel) targeting [Ravager of the Fells](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ravager%20of%20the%20Fells), What side would [Ravager of the Fells](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ravager%20of%20the%20Fells) be on when he came back into the battlefield?

Comment: you mean cards with 'transform' right? and not the flip cards from the kamikawa block? do both questions have the same answer?

Comment: Double-faced cards don't have *sides*, they have *faces*.

Comment: @Colin D, Double-faced cards are the ones that transform, yes. Yes, it's the "same answer" for flip cards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its front face (the one with the sun symbol in the top-left corner), so [Huntmaster of the Fells](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHuntmaster%20of%20the%20Fells%5d).

It's a brand new object put onto the 'field, as if you had just resolved it after casting it. It has summoning sickness; it's untapped; it doesn't have any counters, enchantments or equipment; and it's front face is up.

> 711.5. A double-faced card enters the battlefield with its front face up unless a spell or ability puts it onto the battlefield “transformed,” in which case it enters the battlefield with its back face up.